# How install older OpenJDK 1.6 in Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, fedora-17

I want to install OpenJDK 1.6 in Fedora 17 however I only see OpenJDK 1.7 as an install option when I run `yum search openjdk`. How can I get OpenJDK 1.6 in Fedora 17?

Comment: There is no openjdk 1.6 rpm package supplied for fedora core 17. You could serach for third party rpm for that. And you could install it with `rpm -i path_to_rpm_file` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As scriptmonster stated, 1.6 rpm package is not supplied for fedora core 17. I had to download the rpm and install it that way.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Openjdk 1.6 from Fedora 16. Use this command:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk --releasever=16 --nogpgcheck
```

(`--nogpgcheck` because `yum` complains of not having the key for Fedora 16, maybe there are better ways to solve this)

But this shows, that `java-1.7.0-openjdk` obsoletes `java-1.6.0-openjdk` and skips installation. And it shows that the package `xorg-x11-fonts-Type1` is needed. So I did

```
yum install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

and then I used the openjdk package which `yum` downloaded but refused to install because of the *obsoletes warning*

```
rpm --nodeps -ihv /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/updates/packages/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-68.1.11.5.fc16.x86_64.rpm
```

(`--nodeps` for overriding the *obsoletes warning*)

Now I have both java 1.6 and java 1.7 on my system. Java 1.7 is my default. And Java 1.6 is in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java`.

PS: **There won't be any conflicts** when you install both 1.7 and 1.6. The reason for removing 1.6 from Fedora 17 was, that OpenJDK6 will [no longer get security updates after November 2012](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.general/414703).

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora 26:

```
dnf install sudo dnf install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 
dnf --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=updates --releasever=16  --nogpgcheck  install java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

and select jdk with command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```