# Where do I get the 1.6 open jdk rpm to install on fedora 17

Tags: fedora, openjdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How install older OpenJDK 1.6 in Fedora 17?](https://superuser.com/questions/441757/how-install-older-openjdk-1-6-in-fedora-17)

I note that one can't install the open jdk 1.6 on fedora 17 using yum.

Where does one download the open jdk 1.6 rpm  to install on fedora 17? I've been searching all morning unable to find it.

Also I wonder if I install fedora 16.. will that come with jdk 1.6 by default. Is that a better route to take?

Thanks Much

Comment: Is there a reason why you need 1.6 versus 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Openjdk 1.6 from Fedora 16. Use this command:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk --releasever=16 --nogpgcheck
```

(`--nogpgcheck` because `yum` complains of not having the key for Fedora 16, maybe there are better ways to solve this)

But this shows, that `java-1.7.0-openjdk` obsoletes `java-1.6.0-openjdk` and skips installation. And it shows that the package `xorg-x11-fonts-Type1` is needed. So I did

```
yum install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

and then I used the openjdk package which `yum` downloaded but refused to install because of the *obsoletes warning*

```
rpm --nodeps -ihv /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/updates/packages/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-68.1.11.5.fc16.x86_64.rpm
```

(`--nodeps` for overriding the *obsoletes warning*)

Now I have both java 1.6 and java 1.7 on my system. Java 1.7 is my default. And Java 1.6 is in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java`.

PS: **There won't be any conflicts** when you install both 1.7 and 1.6. The reason for removing 1.6 from Fedora 17 was, that OpenJDK6 will [no longer get security updates after November 2012](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.general/414703).

Answer (score 0):

You can search for it using an rpm search engine like http://rpm.pbone.net/ . Go to advanced search, select Fedora 17 and search for "java-1.6.0-openjdk". I found these links there:

x86_64 : [http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17757925/dir/fedora_17/com/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-65.1.11.fc17.x86_64.rpm.html](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17757928/dir/fedora_17/com/java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc-1.6.0.0-65.1.11.fc17.x86_64.rpm.html)

i386 : http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17729655/dir/fedora_17/com/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-65.1.11.fc17.i686.rpm.html